# Should I answer my own half-answered question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I figured out an issue that I was about to write a question on, since I couldn't find any answers online. But while my answer resolves the immediate issue with a workaround, it raises the question of why my IDE wasn't doing the right thing in the first place. Should I answer my own question with an extra question at the end of my answer, or include the workaround in my question and have the ultimate question be what's wrong with my IDE? Or for that matter, should I separate it into two questions?

I'm sorry if the first couple of sentences are hard to understand; it's hard to be more specific without linking to the question, which I haven't posted yet.

EDIT: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653440/android-studio-adding-id-through-design-gui-generates-errors/39653441#39653441) it is.

Comment: I was in basically the same situation as you a few months ago. [What I did was self-answer with just a workaround anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358867/why-does-my-adaptivetrigger-fire-when-i-change-the-theme-settings), but leave it unaccepted (though a recent development gave me closure to finally accept my answer, with the cause being "it was a bug that has since been fixed").

Comment: Thank you. If someone else doesn't post in the next few minutes (it's almost bedtime), I'll go ahead and hit Post Your Question And Answer and cross my fingers that I'll be able to accept it when it hopefully gets fixed. I'll even post a link once I do hit Post!